# Ajax JSONP Parseerror-Callback-Not-Called with Tomcat 9

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, tomcat, jsonp

I got a problem using my tomcat servlet. I'm trying to cross-site-script on localhost with jsonp. I'm trying to access local the server with ajax/javascript like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/tomtest/test',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
     async: false,
    dataType: 'JSONP',

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error');   console.log(request.status);
        console.log(request.statusText); console.log(request.readyState);
        console.log(textStatus);  console.log(errorThrown);
    }});


mycallback = function(data){alert(data);};
```

My server (tomcat-servlet-java) will response something like this:

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/javascript");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.print(jsonAnswer);
    out.flush();
```

Using firefox to see the answer that i got from server:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apyxe.png)

There is any parsing problem before SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'. How can i parse the answer in json on client-site? I could not solve it with the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It seems like, i have to give the name of mycallback-function on the server. 
**"mycallback("+jsonAnswer+")"** It works.

```
`   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/javascript");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.print("mycallback("+jsonAnswer+")");
    out.flush();`
```